# How to remove NIB cache?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

I have 3 file:

```
MyViewController.h
MyViewController.m
MyViewController.xib
```

MyViewController.xib have some view which i removed? I removed its from xib file but it's still over there. I think xCode cache that views. Anybody can tell me how to remove xCode cache to completely remove its?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always a good idea to do a clean between builds, especially if you see issues like this. For a basic clean, select "Clean" from Xcode's build menu and try again. You should be all set!

Another option is to go into your project directory and delete the "Build" folder. This is sort of a full-on, manual version of a clean, and will force your project to completely rebuild from your nib file.

(Also, make sure you've saved that nib file.)

Comment: what's the view? And how do you know that it's still there?

Comment: 2 UIButton, i removed it from xib but it's still show on my view when i load this xib (After remove 2 UIButton, it's jusst a empty view) :(

Comment: Try what Sam Ritchie said and then delete the app from Simulator/Device.

Comment: You can use the shortcut "command+option+shift+K" to delete the build folder from within Xcode